# roxygenize fails with "missing name" for setAs()

Tags: r, r-s4, roxygen2

I am working on a package which defines its own S4 classes. I define a class and I want to define a method of converting objects of that class to a data frame. The code itself works, but an attempt to generate documentation with `roxygen2` warns as follows:

```
Warning: classes.R:14: Missing name
```

Here is a minimal code snippet:

```
#' The foo class
#' 
#' This is the foo class
#' @slot .Data contains a list 
foo <- setClass("foo", slots=list(.Data="list"))

#' @describeIn foo This is the method to show foo
setMethod("show", "foo", 
  function(object) {
    cat("This is me, foo\n")
  })

#' @describeIn foo This is the method to convert foo to a data frame
setAs("foo", "data.frame", function(from) { 
    data.frame(cbind(from$a, from$b)) 
  })
```

The generated documentation does not contain any information about the `as(x, "data.frame")`. The following works without a warning:

```
#' The foo class
#' 
#' This is the foo class
#' @rdname foo-class
#' @slot .Data contains a list 
foo <- setClass("foo", slots=list(.Data="list"))

#' @rdname foo-class
setMethod("show", "foo",
  function(object) {
    cat("This is me, foo\n")
  })

#' @name as
#' @rdname foo-class
setAs("foo", "data.frame", function(from) { data.frame(cbind(from$a, from$b)) })
```

..however, again, the documentation does not contain any information about the "as" idiom.